# why should I use 'plurals' in RESTAdapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-rails

According to [ember-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/410-ember-part-2),

We should define the the plurals for model ? why ?

MVC's feature is convention over than configuration,

Why should I do it, and for what ?

### app/assets/javascripts/models/store.js.coffee

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", entry: "entries")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you don't need to do this.  Ember has an `Inflector` that can handle most pluralization.

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.pluralize('entry') === 'entries'
```

If it doesn't, you can add your own:

```
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular('formula', 'formulae');     
Ember.Inflector.inflector.uncountable('butter');
```

Ember Inflector is now a separate package and can be used outside of Ember: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-inflector